# PHP - adding ical attachement to mail

Tags: php, html, icalendar

I'm making a basic php reservation system. (see code below)
I want to make the reservation + make an iCal attachement of it and send the mail.
But for some reason my attachement is not being made and just outputted as normal text in the email.

FYI: some tags like  are just to blank out my mail or phone for example.
Not going to post it here :)

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

    $message = "";
    $datum = "";

    //email adres
    $email = "<email>";

    $required = array('dag', 'maand', 'jaar', 'uur', 'minuten', 'naam','email', 'telefoon', 'aantal', 'bericht', 'type');

    if (isset($_POST['reserveren']))
    {
        $data = $_POST['reservatie'];

        $headers = "";

        $message .= "Dag Lode en Eva, via de website kregen jullie een nieuwe reservatie, gelieve de persoon zo snel mogelijk een bevestigingsmail te sturen!";
        $message .= "\n\n";
        $message .= $data['bericht'];
        $message .= "\n\n";

        $message .= "Telefoon: " . $data['telefoon'];
        $message .= "\n\n";
        $message .= "Lunch/Diner: " . $data['type'];
        $message .= "\n\n"; 
        $message .= "Aantal personen: " . $data['aantal'];
        $message .= "\n\n";
        $message .= "Email: " . $data['email'];
        $message .= "\n\n";

        $message .= "Datum: " . $data['dag'];
        $message .= "\n\n";
        $message .= "Maand: " . $data['maand'];
        $message .= " " . $data['jaar'];
        $message .= "\n\n";
        $message .= "Tijdstip: " . $data['uur'] . " " . $data['minuten'];       
        $message .= "\n\n";

        $naam = $data['naam'];
        $datum = $data['dag'] ."/". "1" ."/". $data['jaar']; 
        $mail = $data['email'];
        $plaats = "Baronie";
        $omschrijving = "reservering";

        //Create ICAL Content
        $ical =    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
        PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
        VERSION:2.0
        METHOD:PUBLISH
        BEGIN:VEVENT
        ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'.$mail.'
        DTSTART:'.$datum.'
        LOCATION:'.$plaats.'
        TRANSP:OPAQUE
        SEQUENCE:0
        DESCRIPTION:'.$omschrijving.'
        SUMMARY:'.$subject.'
        PRIORITY:5
        CLASS:PUBLIC
        END:VEVENT
        END:VCALENDAR';   

        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="reservering.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
        $message .= $ical;

        $subject = 'Nieuwe reservatie via de website';
        $headers = 'From: '. $data['email']. "\r\n" .'Reply-To: '. $data['email']. "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo "mail verstuurd!";

    }
?>
```

**Email output**

```
Dag Lode en Eva, via de website kregen jullie een nieuwe reservatie, gelieve de persoon zo snel mogelijk een bevestigingsmail te sturen!

met cal

Telefoon: <phone>

Lunch/Diner: Diner

Aantal personen: 10

Email: <mail>

Datum: 01

Maand: Januari 2015

Tijdstip: 12 00

Content-Type: text/calendar;name="reservering.ics";method=REQUEST\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
        PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
        VERSION:2.0
        METHOD:PUBLISH
        BEGIN:VEVENT
        ORGANIZER:MAILTO:<my email address here>
        DTSTART:01/1/2015
        LOCATION:Baronie
        TRANSP:OPAQUE
        SEQUENCE:0
        DESCRIPTION:reservering
        SUMMARY:
        PRIORITY:5
        CLASS:PUBLIC
        END:VEVENT
        END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards!

Comment: I'd suggest you to have a a look at [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It'll handle the Attachments and generation of MIME-Emails for you, and makes your code much easier and more easy to modify.

Comment: how I see it is that PHPMailer helpst with sending the mails and you can configure your SMTP, etc without needing a mailserver. But nothing about creating or helping with the ical attachement generation? This is done by writing the code manually I think. Can't find any decent working example tho.

Comment: If you want to attach it as a file (needs to be clicked), it'll be very easy using PHPMailer. If you need it to show as an invitation in the recipient's calendar application, PHPMailer won't be really easy (however it has some helper to send such invitations)

Comment: it only needs to be attached inside the mail, the receiver needs to open it and add it to his calendar. So out of curiosity how would I use PHPMailer to make this work??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHPMailer is ok, the following should to the job. Please note i stripped it down a litte bit, but i think the Code should be easy enough to understand it.

```
<?php

//Of course, you can even include PHPmailer class directly!
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
define('CRLF',"\r\n");

//do your processing here - assuming the variables are filled as follows:
$from='some@mail.address';
$to='some@persons.address';
$subject='someSubject';
$message='Hello World!';

$starttime=time();  //note that you need to supply a unix timestamp here!
$endtime=time()+3600;

//of course assuming the variables used in the attachments are accordingly set
$attachment='BEGIN:VCALENDAR'.CRLF.
            'VERSION:2.0'.CRLF.
            'PRODID:-//question_on//stackoverflow.com//EN'.CRLF.
            'BEGIN:VEVENT'.CRLF.
            'UID:'.md5(uniqid()).CRLF.
            'DTSTAMP:'.date('Ymd')."T".date('His').CRLF.
            'DTSTART:'.date('Ymd',$starttime)."T".date('His',$starttime).CRLF.
            'DTEND:'.date('Ymd',$endtime)."T".date('His',$endtime).CRLF.
            'LOCATION:somewhere'.CRLF.
            'DESCRIPTION:Some Description, if it should be multiline\,'.CRLF.
            '    the following lines need to be indentend by a single tab'.CRLF.
            'SUMMARY:test Event'.CRLF.
            'PRIORITY:5'.CRLF.
            'END:VEVENT'.CRLF.
            'END:VCALENDAR'.CRLF;
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->isMail();
/*
If you later decide to use smtp instead of php's mail-function, just use the following lines
instead of 'isMail()'
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mail.youmailprovider.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'yourSMTPUser';
$mail->Password = 'password';
*/
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->addStringAttachment($attachment,'filename_to_show.ics','base64','text/calendar');
$mail->Body=$message;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo  "Message sent!";
}
```